# Spring SimpleKey collision?

Tags: spring, caching, redis, hash-collision

I just found that [SimpleKeyGenerator](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/SimpleKeyGenerator.java) returns a [SimpleKey](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/SimpleKey.java) which concerns method parameters only.

Say, what if, following two different service methods have same parameters?

```
@Cacheable
long countInAWay(..., ..., ...);

@Cacheable
long countInADifferentWay(..., ..., ...);
```

What happen to the cache when these two methods are invoke with exactly the same parameters? Do those keys collide?

Comment: Can't you specify `@Cacheable("countInAWay")` and  `@Cacheable("countInADifferentWay")` to explicetly differentiate them?

Comment: @StanislavL Of course, I can. Is it the best way? Thank you.

Comment: In theory it's possible to extend the @Cacheable to use e.g. class name + method name but what if you have 2 versions of the same class loaded in e.g. two different web applications on the same server. There could be different strategies.